# combine all values associated with the key from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have a json string as shown below

```
[{"_id":"9/17/2015","amt1":0,"amt2":13276.5},{"_id":"9/18/2015","amt1":8075,"amt2":6445.5}]
```

Expected Result:

```
[{"_id": ["9/17/2015", "9/18/2015"], "amt1": [0, 8075], "amt2": [13276.5, 6445.5]}]
```

Is this be achievable without loop. As the json may have more than 500 records..

Can any on help to get the desired output..

Comment: it is better to do it server side if this is from ajax response.

Comment: this isn't a code writing service. Show code you tried to solve this yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go:

```js
var data = [{"_id":"9/17/2015","amt1":0,"amt2":13276.5},{"_id":"9/18/2015","amt1":8075,"amt2":6445.5}];

var groupByKeys = function(data) {
  var obj = {};
  for(var i in data) {
    var curr = data[i];
    for(var key in curr) {
      if(!obj[key]) obj[key] = [];
      obj[key].push(curr[key]);
    }
  }
  
  return obj;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(groupByKeys(data)));
```

Comment: @user3211705 of course it can't be done without loop.... resultant is dependent on each element in existing array

Comment: cant be done with no loop. nope. but 500 recoeds is not a lot for this code. try it with lots of records and tell us how long it took.